# Does the location of requiredField (inside a ListView) has incidence on the way ValidationSummary display errors?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have 2 RequiredFieldValidator controls inside a ListView. When validation occurs, the ValidationSummary control located at the top of the page (outside of the ListView) doesn't display any error.

**EDIT**

Here's the code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="_txtClientName" width="75px" runat="server" TabIndex="4" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="_btnSearch" CssClass="grey_button" width="50px" runat="server" Text="Search" 
     TabIndex="5" CommandArgument="search" ValidationGroup = "SearchClientName" />


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqSearch" runat="server" Text = "*" ErrorMessage="Please enter  criteria to search" ControlToValidate = "_txtClientName" ValidationGroup = "SearchClientName" />
```

The summaryValidation control is located outside the ListView, at the very top of the page.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" ShowSummary = "true" runat="server" />
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your two RequiredFieldValidators  : `Display="None"`

And to your summary : `ShowSummary="true"`

Comment: I have added the above code, but the summery's still not there.

Comment: ErrorMessage on each validator

Comment: Ok Richard i look, but where is your summary ?? and your second validator ?

Comment: Add Display="None" to your validator, i mentioned in my answer Richard